# Admin grid action column layout is broken after upgrading to 2.4.4

Tags: ui-form, magento2.4.4, grid-layout

Previously i'm using magento v2.4.1 in cms grid the action column is showing the correct layout after getting clicked, for example Block cms grid:

[image]

The layout is overlapping the grid correctly, however after i upgrade to 2.4.4 i need to scroll down to see the entire action column options:

[image]

Comment: Hi there, did u check if there is any CSS applied for admin side grid settings ? , and does this breakout apply to all the grids in the admin interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a styling issue native to 2.4.4. This can be easily fix by setting the `over-flow-x:unset` to `.admin__data-grid-wrap`

Comment: Can u tell me from where i can add the custom css to Grid